# django wysiwyg text editor doesn't work properly with Android

Tags: python, django, django-admin, wysiwyg

I'm currently using [summernote](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote) in my admin panel where I can put text and images and in DB it will save the formatted content by applying some html tags `<b>`, `<i>`, etc.

but when I render that content using json api to android, it doesn't use html formatting correctly.

now let me tell you my actual case scenario. I'm creating an application similar to Quora. its a simple app where users can post question and users can answer. in their question detail or answer they can attach images as well.

now for me here order of image does matter(similar to Quora again), I mean when user attach some image after some text it should be save in db in that order. I can't save text at one place and images in another place, in that case i wont be able to recognize the actual position of text and images. I mean where should I put image1 in this whole text, after line1? line5? line7?.

Django-summernote solved the problem about image positioning but not the formatting. is there any better library or approach to maintain image positioning and text formatting to support web and mobile application(through JSON api).

PS:  from here https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/wysiwyg/
`django-summernote` seems to be the best

Comment: Show relevant code, and the results you get along with what results you wish to have

Comment: "it doesn't use html formatting correctly." Do you turn off autoescape during rendering? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape Perhaps it might be the culprit